# System.String' does not contain a property with the name 'Key'

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5

I am trying to recreate what was explained in the answer [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7653258/binding-dropdownlistfor-helper-to-a-dictionary) SO answer
but I am getting this error that doesn't make any sense me because I did exactly what the answer said...

I should say that I'm relatively new to this so all any help is greatly appreciated. Thank you !

Block that throws the error in View

```
<div class="form-group">
    @Html.LabelFor(m => m.CustomerNumber, new { @class = "col-md-2 control-label" })
    <div class="col-md-10">
        @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.CustomerNumber, Model.AvailableCustNum)
    </div>
</div>
```

ViewModel

```
public class RegisterViewModel
{
    [Required]
    [EmailAddress]
    [Display(Name = "Email")]
    public string Email { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [Display(Name = "User Name")]
    [StringLength(50, ErrorMessage = "The {0} must be at least {2} characters long.", MinimumLength = 5)]
    public string UserName { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [StringLength(100, ErrorMessage = "The {0} must be at least {2} characters long.", MinimumLength = 6)]
    [DataType(DataType.Password)]
    [Display(Name = "Password")]
    public string Password { get; set; }

    [DataType(DataType.Password)]
    [Display(Name = "Confirm password")]
    [System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Compare("Password", ErrorMessage = "The password and confirmation password do not match.")]
    public string ConfirmPassword { get; set; }

    [DataType(DataType.PhoneNumber)]
    [Display(Name = "Phone Number")]
    public string PhoneNumber { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [Display(Name = "Customer Number")]
    public string CustomerNumber { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [Display(Name = "DeptID")]
    public int DeptID { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [Display(Name = "Department Name")]
    public string DepartmentName { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [Display(Name = "Group")]
    public string Group { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [Display(Name = "Address Line 1")]
    public string AddressLine1 { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Address Line 2")]
    public string AddressLine2 { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [Display(Name = "City")]
    public string City { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [Display(Name = "State")]
    public string State { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [Display(Name = "Zip Code")]
    public string Zip { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [Display(Name = "Country")]
    public string Country { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [Display(Name = "UACC")]
    public int UACC { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [Display(Name = "IsRecordCenter")]
    public bool IsRecCenter { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [Display(Name = "IsCustAdmin")]
    public bool IsCustAdmin { get; set; }


    public SelectList AvailableGroups { get; set; }

    public SelectList AvailableCustNum { get; set; }

    public SelectList AvailableDept { get; set; }


}
```

Controller

```
public ActionResult Register()
    { 
        RecordCenterLoginRepo RCLR = new RecordCenterLoginRepo();
        IdentityCheck IDC = new IdentityCheck();

        var recCenID = RCLR.GetRecordCenterID((string)Session["RecordCenter"]);


        Dictionary<string,int> custNums = IDC.GetAvailableCustomerNumbers(recCenID);
        Dictionary<string,int> depts = IDC.GetAvailableDepartments((string)Session["CustomerNumber"], recCenID);
        Dictionary<string,int> groups = IDC.GetAvailableGroups((string)Session["CustomerNumber"], recCenID);

        RegisterViewModel model = new RegisterViewModel() {

            AvailableCustNum = new SelectList(custNums, "Key", "Value"),
            AvailableDept = new SelectList(depts, "Key", "Value"),
            AvailableGroups = new SelectList(groups, "Key", "Value")
        };

        return View(model);
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

The 2nd and 3rd parameters of `SelectList()` are the string names of the value and text fields respectively. Does `IDC.GetAvailableCustomerNumbers(recCenID)` return a `Dictionary<string, string>`? The example you cited uses a Dictionary in their code, which is why the "Key, Values" string work. If you are using an `IEnumerable<T>`, try the property names on the model instead of "Key" and "Value".

Comment: They all return a `Dictionary<string, int>`

Comment: I see that in now in your example. I'm assuming you aren't getting any compilation errors with that? The error you are getting means that you are trying to access a property of "Key" on a string. 

I would double check the return value of your repository and adjust from there. See this answer for someone who had a similar problem: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6705488/dropdownlistfor-throws-an-error#answer-6708179